# type-id c ключевыми словами const и volatile в const_cast

Tags: c++, очередь, const, volatile

Итак, существует [интеловский код](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/single-producer-single-consumer-queue/) по реализации потокобезопасной очереди "один пишет - один читает".

Там, как вы заметили, есть конструкции примерно такого типа:

```
const_cast <const volatile node*> (param) //это в load_consume
const_cast <volatile node*> (param) // это в store_release.
```

Вопрос состоит в том, для чего нужны эти ключевые слова в const_cast и чем они отличаются (а видимо, они отличаются) от стандартной конструкции по типу `const_cast <node*> (param)`?

---

*А это не относится конкретно к вопросу, тут мои попытки пояснить код. Возможно, это поможет понять кому-то (но пока что не мне), зачем там вообще `const_cast`?*

Если интересно насчёт того, что есть там конкретно по этим двум методам, то, насколько я понял, то все узлы (`node`), а именно `head`, `tail`, `next`, `tail_copy` и `first` обозначены как указатели на некие объекты, построенные в соответствии со структурой `node` (в нём лежит ссылка на следующий узел и значение). То есть, это всё объявляется как `node*` и выглядит в остальных местах как `&node`.

`load_consume` по своей логике принимает указатель и возвращает значение по ней, но по факту это значение из-за выше указанных вещей - тоже указатель. Указатель на этот указатель мы и передаём в качестве параметра в этот метод. Также он делает `const_cast`, о котором я спрашивал, и вызывает барьер памяти, который говорит процессорам, чтобы завершали все свои незавершённые операции.

Один раз `load_consume` используется, чтобы проверить, не пуста ли очередь: он пытается взять этот указатель на `tail->next`, если "не смог" (видимо, в самом конце лежит нулевое значение), то считается, что больше ничего в очереди нет.

В другом месте (`alloc_node`) он просто передаёт одному указателю другой указатель.

`store_release` принимает указатель и значение, затем разыменовывает первое и даёт значение второго. Как говорил, всё это является указателями, то есть, разыменованному указателю на указатель даётся "значение" на другой указатель. Также там тоже есть барьер памяти.

---

*И уж совсем не по теме, но по их коду, отвечать совсем не обязательно: зачем там нужны `cache_line_size` и `cache_line_pad`, а также конструкция ниже?*

```
spsc_queue(spsc_queue const&);
spsc_queue& operator = (spsc_queue const&);
```

Comment: У меня было 2 основных варианта ответа на мой вопрос, что делает `const_cast <const volatile type*>`: или так можно указать, какой именно именно спецификатор удалить, или, наоборот, придаёт чему-то этот спецификатор (не удаляет).  
И, судя по логике кода, тут как раз второе. В `load_consume`  никакое внешнее содержимое (параметр) не меняется, а значит, этот параметр можно сделать константой. Ну и в обоих случаях мы, собственно, добавляем ещё `volatile`.  
  
Мне осталось выяснить, каков ответ на последний вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный код, либо я чего-то не знаю про интеловский компилятор, либо код писал не совсем грамотный программист. Так, ни в одном из этих случаев `const_cast` не нужен. Достаточно простого и понятного `static_cast`:

```
static_cast <const volatile node*> (param) //это в load_consume
static_cast <volatile node*> (param) // это в store_release.
```

Теперь, для чего нужен `volatile`: раньше, когда не был утверждён стандарт C++ 11 года, `volatile` был единственным кроссплатформенным способом заставить компилятор читать именно последнее значение того или иного объекта, т.е. никакого кэширования со стороны компилятора не происходит. Остаётся одна деталь — процессор может и будет кэшировать объекты, поэтому в коде находятся барьеры(конкретно в этой версии кода барьеры для компилятора, но не для `addr`, а для других объектов, т.к. в x86 CPU барьеры для этих случаев не требуются).

Используя volatile+memory barriers достигается гарантированное получение последних значений объектов, что необходимо для синхронизации.

Если интересно почитать про барьеры памяти, volatile и о том как сейчас дела обстоят в C++, то можете почитать мои статьи: [по барьерам](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/05/16/memory_barriers.aspx), по современному C++: [раз](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/08/14/parallel-world-p4.aspx) и [два](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/10/15/parallel_world_p5.aspx)

---

Зачем нужен `cache_line_pad`: как Вы можете видеть, в коде есть разделение на данные потребителя и поставщика, и подразумевается, что данные будут использоваться из разных потоков. Но если получится так, что данные поставщика и потребителя находятся в одной линии кэш, тогда получится ситуация, что кэш линия будет «портиться» то одним потоком, то другим, из-за этого будет постоянный траффик между кэш-блоками разных ядер. Это ухудшит производительность, может даже сильно. Поэтому код гарантирует, что данные, которые должны быть использованы в разных потоках, находятся в разных линиях кэш.

---

Зачем нужны строки:

```
spsc_queue(spsc_queue const&);
spsc_queue& operator = (spsc_queue const&);
```

Они нужны для того, чтобы запретить копирование структуры `spsc_queue`, как Вы можете видеть, обе метода находятся в `private` секции и не имеют реализации, поэтому при попытке копирования `spsc_queue` компилятор выдаст ошибку.

P.S. в следующий раз создавайте отдельные темы для разных вопросов, а не набивайте несколько не смежных вопросов в один.