# Потокобезопасная очередь

Tags: c++, многопоточность, очередь

Начну с предыстории.

Итак, мне нужен пример потокобезопасной очереди на C++ категории "один пишет - один читает". Искал на разных сайтах и, казалось, что-то интересное и откопал: [вот он, этот код](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/single-producer-single-consumer-queue/).

Но дальше меня кое-что насторожило. Точнее, я кое-чего не понял и стал разыскивать в различных справочниках по типу MSDN и cppreference, в разных блогах, но увы. Обратился сюда, а именно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516183/type-id-c-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-const-%D0%B8-volatile-%D0%B2-const-cast).

И теперь у меня некоторое сомнение насчёт того кода. Да и сам бы я кое-что поменял, в основном, мне непонятно предназначение там метода `alloc_node()`. Нет, логику алгоритмов оттуда мне не стоит разъяснять, она, кажется, достаточно очевидна, и я её уяснил. Только вот я считаю, что там введены два лишних указателя `first` и `tail_copy`, и метод этот не нужен, а "писателя" стоит переписать: дело в том, что, судя по всему, его данные считаются читателем, но так и будут висеть в памяти, пока не уничтожатся деструктором или перезапишутся. Это бы пригодилось в случае, когда их нужно было бы видеть повторно, но в такой ситуации, я думаю, требовался двусвязный список, или кольцо, или хотя бы библиотека ключей - а в том коде этого нет, есть только указатель `next` в каждом узле, и этого недостаточно. Создавать спецуказатель, постоянно показывающий конец очереди, а потом проходить по нему, тоже не очень, по-моему.

Я не претендую на звание знатока, я новичок, не гоните меня взашей, но мне кажется, так было бы лучше (с барьерами пока не разбирался, если они тут нужны). Это не вопрос, больше мысли вслух, может, будет нужно для ответа / кому-то пригодится (если вообще работает):

```
~spsc_queue() {
    if(load_consume(&tail) == nullptr) return; // если уже всё удалено до
    if(load_consume(&tail->next) == nullptr) {
        delete tail; return;
    }  // если есть только начальное звено от конструктора
    do {
        node * next = tail->next;
        delete tail;
        store_release(&tail, next);
    } while(load_consume(&tail) != nullptr);
}

// другой поток (читатель) обязательно должен понимать,
// что сначала должно быть записано значение в ячейку,
// а уже потом эта ячейка станет для него видима,
// то есть, она станет подключенной к очереди
void enqueue(T v) {
    node* n = new node;
    n->next = nullptr;
    n->value = v;
    if(load_consume(&head) != nullptr) { // на всякий случай
        store_release(&head->next, n);
    } // тут подключается к очереди
    head = n;
}

// удаляется все считанное, кроме пустого начального звена, 
// который создаётся конструктором
bool dequeue(T& v) {
    if(load_consume(&tail->next) != nullptr) {
        v = tail->next - > value;
        node * next = tail->next->next;
        delete tail->next;
        store_release(&tail->next, next);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Писатель пользуется только `head`, читатель - только `tail`.
Если честно, даже не проверял, как работает. Просто статьи со scrutator'а читал, да и вообще, некогда было.

Ладно, наконец, долгожданный вопрос: вероятно, в том коде с сайта интел есть ещё какие-то недочёты или что-либо в этом духе. Мне это всё не очевидно. Мне бы хотелось знать, в чём там ещё может быть дело, чтобы я мог это учесть. Либо, пожалуйста, ссылку на пример кода без помарок и с реализацией барьеров и без зависимости от платформы. Либо сюда. Желательно, чтобы подходило также под x64. Спасибо.

Comment: Как например (раз уж c++) [gist](https://gist.github.com/vladimirgamalian/9f24df88de7de6b242ab17e64688d897)

Comment: Вот же есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428867/10105

Comment: Думаю, всё-таки boost, блокировки и "многие читают, многие пишут" для меня избыточны, но всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что не хотите использовать **тривиальный pipe в качестве очереди**?

Смотрите, простая программка на основе [producer/consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428867/232)

```
// это поток-потребитель
void *
consumer_thread (void *arg)
{
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = (typeof(q))arg;
  long long sum = 0, nc = 0, ns = 0;

  for (;;) {
    void *data = dequeue(q);
    // это сигнал, что очередь окончена
    if (!data)
      break; // значит, пора закрывать поток

    char *str = (char *)data;
    // тут наша обработка данных
    ns++;
    //   puts(str);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
      sum += str[i];
    nc += (i - 1);

    free(str);
  }

  printf("consumed %lld strings %lld chars (%lld)\n", ns, nc, sum);

  return 0;
}

int
main ()
{
  pthread_t consumer_threads[2];
  void *res = 0;
  char *in = NULL;

  // создадим очередь:
  struct producer_consumer_queue *q = producer_consumer_queue_create();

  // и потоки-«потребители»
  //  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[0], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);
  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[0], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);

  // главный цикл
  int i, n = 100000;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int l = (rand() % 100 + 1) * 50;
    in = (char *)malloc(l--);
    in[l--] = 0;
    while (l >= 0)
      in[l--] = rand() % ('~' - ' ') + ' ';
    enqueue(in, q);
    in = NULL;
  }

  producer_consumer_queue_stop(q);
  if (pthread_join(consumer_threads[0], &res))
    perror("join");

  return (long)res;
}
```

создает и заполняет строки в одном потоке, подсчитывает количество байт,  суммирует их и освобождает память в другом. Адреса строк передаются через очередь на мьютексах.

**Она выполняется за 5.5sec.**

То же самое, с реализацией очереди на pipe

```
struct pipe {
  int p[2];
};

void
enqueue (void *data, struct pipe *p)
{
  if (write(p->p[1], &data, sizeof(data)) != sizeof(data))
    close(p->p[1]);
}

void *
dequeue(struct pipe *p)
{
  void *data;

  if (read(p->p[0], &data, sizeof(data)) != sizeof(data))
    data = 0;

  return data;
}

struct pipe *
producer_consumer_queue_create()
{
  struct pipe *p = (__typeof__(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));

  if (pipe(p->p))
    p = 0;

  return p;
}


void
producer_consumer_queue_stop(struct pipe *q)
{
  void *d = 0;

  if (write(q->p[1], &d, sizeof(d)) == sizeof(d))
    close(q->p[1]);
}

// это поток-потребитель
void *
consumer_thread (void *arg)
{
  struct pipe *q = (typeof(q))arg;
  long long sum = 0, nc = 0, ns = 0;

  for (;;) {
    void *data = dequeue(q);
    // это сигнал, что очередь окончена
    if (!data)
      break; // значит, пора закрывать поток

    char *str = (char *)data;
    // тут наша обработка данных
    ns++;
    //   puts(str);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
      sum += str[i];
    nc += (i - 1);

    free(str);
  }

  close(q->p[0]);
  printf("consumed %lld strings %lld chars (%lld)\n", ns, nc, sum);

  return 0;
}

int
main ()
{
  pthread_t consumer_threads[2];
  void *res = 0;
  char *in = NULL;

  // создадим очередь:
  struct pipe *q = producer_consumer_queue_create();

  // и потоки-«потребители»
  //  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[0], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);
  pthread_create(&consumer_threads[0], 0, consumer_thread, (void *)q);

  // главный цикл
  int i, n = 100000;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int l = (rand() % 100 + 1) * 50;
    in = (char *)malloc(l--);
    in[l--] = 0;
    while (l >= 0)
      in[l--] = rand() % ('~' - ' ') + ' ';
    enqueue(in, q);
    in = NULL;
  }

  producer_consumer_queue_stop(q);
  if (pthread_join(consumer_threads[0], &res))
    perror("join");

  return (long)res;
}
```

**уже 5.3sec** (по крайней мере не хуже, но значительно проще).

Если не боитесь дополнительного уровня буферизации (`FILE *`), то с 
незначительными модификациями, вроде

```
struct pipe {
  FILE *p[2];
};


struct pipe *
producer_consumer_queue_create()
{
  struct pipe *p = (__typeof__(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
  int pp[2];

  if (pipe(pp))
    p = 0;
  else {
    p->p[0] = fdopen(pp[0], "r");
    p->p[1] = fdopen(pp[1], "w");
  }

  return p;
}
```

время выполнения той же работы **снижается уже до 4.8sec**. Да, реактивность в такой системе ниже.

Для сравнения, однопоточный вариант со всеми malloc/free

```
int
main ()
{
  char *in = NULL;
  long long sum = 0, nc = 0, ns = 0;

  // главный цикл
  int i, n = 100000;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int l = (rand() % 100 + 1) * 50;
    in = (char *)malloc(l--);
    in[l--] = 0;
    while (l >= 0)
      in[l--] = rand() % ('~' - ' ') + ' ';

    //    enqueue(in, q);
    ns++;
    //   puts(str);

    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; in[ii]; ii++)
      sum += in[ii];
    nc += (ii - 1);

    free(in);

    in = NULL;
  }

  printf("consumed %lld strings %lld chars (%lld)\n", ns, nc, sum);

  return 0;
}
```

отработает за 2.7sec.

P.S.
На какие мысли все это наводит?

Answer (score 2):

Я хочу предупредить, я не вникал в код полностью — для анализа многопоточных структур данных нужно время, а для неблокирующих нужно ещё больше. Тем не менее, отвечу по Вашему вопросу: функция `alloc_node()` нужна в этом коде, т.к. в ней, помимо того, что улучшается производительность за счёт переиспользования ранее выделенных узлов, там ещё и присваивается `first_`,— указатель, который нужен, как я понял, для освобождения освобождённых узлов.

Действительно, переменная `tail_copy_` уровня класса не нужна, её можно было бы сделать локальной — от этого код бы только выиграл, вообще, мне код не нравится. Он неряшливый и к нему множество вопросов. Тем не менее, я неоднократно сталкивался с текстами Дмитрия Вьюкова на различных ресурсах, и лично у меня нет ни тени сомнения в его компетенции, в части написания многопоточных структур данных и алгоритмов. Безусловно, это не значит, что он пишет красивый С++ код; по крайней мере 7 лет назад он написал очень некрасивый код.

Что касается Вашего кода: как я уже сказал, анализировать подобный код довольно сложно и вряд ли кто-то этим будет заниматься — я точно не стану, поэтому тут придётся набивать свои собственные шишки. Поверьте на слово, на проверку корректности алгоритма могут уйти часы, а то и дни у людей, которые этим профессионально занимаются. Насколько мне известно, таких профессионалов на данном ресурсе нет. Нет их и на английской части, по крайней мере их нет там постоянно и попасть на них сложно.